# Laravel with() Eloquent as variable or another array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, eloquent-relationship

I have this Eloquent query that want to display the orders by day, yesterday, week, last week, this month, last month, this year, last year and this is my code however, it does not work or do have any idea to re do the code. In my sample code I do not know how to put into another each with() query with different parameters. Please help.

```
$product_orders = Product::where('status', 'active')
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', today());
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::yesterday());
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()]);
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', [now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(), now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek()]);
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->whereYear('created_at', '=', now()->year);
        $query->whereMonth('created_at', '=', now()->month);
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->toDateString();
        $tillDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->toDateString();
        $parse_fromDate = Carbon::parse($fromDate.' 00:00:00');
        $parse_tillDate = Carbon::parse($tillDate.' 23:59:59');
        $query->with('order');
        $query->whereBetween('created_at',[$parse_fromDate,$parse_tillDate]);
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->whereYear('created_at', '>=', now()->year);
    }])
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $last_year = now()->year - 1;
        $query->with('order');
        $query->whereYear('created_at', '>=', $last_year);
    }])
    ->get();
```

Comment: I think your approach is a bit counter-productive. If your code were to work as expected you'd perform 16 queries when you can achieve the same with 3 queries and some filtering on the result.

Comment: @apokryfos, can you suggest a redo of my code? I do not know what would be the best in this approach. please help

Answer (score 2):

With this approach, you're essentially overwriting each "with" with the next one in the chain, so that the only thing that is actually executed is the final "with".

What you will need to do is break these into separate queries, with separate result sets, since, at the core you appear to want result from multiple different queries with different criteria.

```
$todays_orders = Product::where('status', 'active')
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', today());
    }])
    ->get();

$yesterdays_orders = Product::where('status', 'active')
    ->with(['order_detail' => function($query) {
        $query->with('order');
        $query->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::yesterday());
    }])
    ->get();

... etc...
```

Comment: I cannot break this into separate queries. all I have in mind it to put this with() in a  array for each queries but I do not know how..

Answer (score 0):

Use the query:

```
$product_orders = Product::where('status', 'active')
   ->with([ 'order_detail' => function ($query) {
        $last_year = now()->year - 1;
        $query->whereYear('created_at', '>=', $last_year); 
    }, 'order_detail.order' ])->get();

$product_orders->each(function (Product $product) {
    $product->today_orders = $product->order_detail->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today());
    $product->today_orders = $product->order_detail->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::yesterday(), Carbon::today() ]);
    $product->weeks_orders = $product->order_detail->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek() ]);
    $product->last_weeks_orders = $product->order_detail->whereBetween('created_at', [ Carbon::now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek() ]);
     // and so on
});
```

Then in your view each product *should* have properties that were set in the `each`

Answer (score 0):

I found my own solution by creating it with filter inside the Model

in Controller

```
$product_orders = Product::where('status', 'active')
    ->with('order_detail_today', 'order_detail_yesterday', 'order_detail_this_week',
        'order_detail_last_week','order_detail_this_month', 'order_detail_last_month',
        'order_detail_this_year', 'order_detail_last_year')->get();
```

in Model

```
public function order_detail_today()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', today());
    }
    public function order_detail_yesterday()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::yesterday());
    }
    public function order_detail_this_week()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', [now()->startOfWeek(), now()->endOfWeek()]);
    }
    public function order_detail_last_week()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->where('created_at', '>=', [now()->subWeek()->startOfWeek(), now()->subWeek()->endOfWeek()]);
    }
    public function order_detail_this_month()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '=', now()->year)
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', now()->month);
    }
    public function order_detail_last_month()
    {
        $fromDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth()->toDateString();
        $tillDate = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()->toDateString();
        $parse_fromDate = Carbon::parse($fromDate.' 00:00:00');
        $parse_tillDate = Carbon::parse($tillDate.' 23:59:59');
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '=', now()->year)
            ->whereBetween('created_at',[$parse_fromDate,$parse_tillDate]);
    }
    public function order_detail_this_year()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '>=', now()->year);
    }
    public function order_detail_last_year()
    {
        $last_year = now()->year - 1;
        return $this->hasMany('App\Order_detail','reference_number')
            ->where('order_type', '!=', 'package')
            ->with('order')
            ->whereYear('created_at', '>=', $last_year);
    }
```

Comment: By doing this, you are actually breaking into separate queries anyway, since each relation (which is what you have here) is in itself a separate query. So there's no real practical gain. The solution by @apokryfos will work as well with a single query, then you're just filtering on the client.